# How do I "test" name-based virtual hosting?

Tags: domain-name-system, virtualhost

Our website `mysite.com` is going to be hosted at a server with virtual hosting (name-based) at `10.20.30.40`. However, the DNS records are currently pointing to `66.77.88.99`.

I want to **keep** those DNS records pointing to `66.77.88.99` while testing; is there any way for me to access `10.20.30.40` anyway?

*Since the target server uses virtual hosting, I cannot simply enter the IP address to test on the target site. Also, I have no control over the target server, and can therefore not set up a subdomain to test on.*

Comment: Use nc netcat and submit a request manually?  Use check_http https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_http.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put the host names with appropriate IP address in your `hosts` file (`/etc/hosts` in Linux, `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows systems) like this:

```
# IP address of your test host     FQDN of your domain
10.20.30.40                        www.mysite.com
```

Do not forget to remove the entries after testing.

Answer (score 13):

As pointed out adding it to `/etc/hosts` is one option.

I usually use the [Modify Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/) Firefox Addon.
I don't have to change system configuration and become root everytime I want to test this.

Another way is using `cURL` like this:

```
curl -H "Host: mysite.com" http://10.20.30.40
```

This is especially useful for quick troubleshooting.
And you don't have to remove anything after you are done.

Comment: Instead of setting the Host header (which presumably only works for HTTP, not HTTPS with SNI), you could also use the `--resolv` option: `curl --resolve example.com:80:192.0.2.1 --resolve example.com:443:192.0.2.2 http://example.com/`

Comment: @Lekensteyn That is correct, it wouldn't work then with `cURL`. Wasn't thinking about SNI.