# check website through IP address

Tags: vps, ip-address, url

I hosted **multiple websites** on a **single VPS server**, with single IP address when I entered IP address in as url it shows default website page that fine

but i hosted multiple website in a single server by creating different directories for each domain 
and hosted 
eg1.com at- `/var/www/eg1.com` 
eg2.com at- `/var/www/eg2.com`  
eg3.com at- `/var/www/eg3.com`

`it's wont work in this wa - ip/var/www/eg1.com`  
 
how can I access my website `eg1.com`, `eg2.com`, `eg3.com` using my **IP address** 
I want to check website status before changing the DNS

please guys this default answer by editing hosts file in drivers, is not the solution for accessing multiple site form the same ip address

```
#   129.0.0.2       eg1.com
```

as this address only one website

**Hosted multiple websites in a single ip address server.
and have to access multiple site**

Comment: Hi @hbruijn as i hosted multiple websites on a single server, think this is not a duplicate question.  i didn't get the solution from the answers what you marked as duplicate.

Comment: you can add all of the hosts names after the IP address in your host file: `1.2.3.4 eg1.com eg2.com eg3.com`

Comment: @David did you mean myip_address/eg1.com , its not working

Comment: IP address followed by the names all on one line with spaces or tabs between them. This will work exactly the same as changing the DNS entry except it is local to the computer with the host file (the computer you are testing from).

Comment: @David can you make this as an answer so that viewers can find the answer easily

Answer (score 2):

I can't mark an answer as a duplicate or comment yet so this'll have to go in as an answer.

This question has already been answered here:

[How do I "test" name-based virtual hosting?](https://serverfault.com/questions/569810/how-do-i-test-name-based-virtual-hosting)

In summary, you can edit your hosts file to point a name at the IP address. This should let the name based configuration respond to the correct host name.

The other option is to use curl with the parameters provided in the link.

Comment: flagged it for you

Comment: Thank you. I don't think I'm too far off being able to do that myself lol.

Comment: have to access multiple websites using same ip address

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in answer above, you can change hosts file on your computer. Great guild:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

Also, my favourite for quick website check on new/test/dev server:
http://propagationproxy.com/

Enter domain name in first box and IP of new server in second and there you are!

Comment: have to access multiple websites using same ip address